# How do I change the date format in a dataframe column.

Tags: time-series, python, date

I have a column in a DataFrame with dates in yyyymmdd format and I need to change it permanently to yyyy-mm-dd.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the data type of the column? What does `print df[<column name>].dtype` shows?

Comment: It is: int64 cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the info you provided in your comment, the column values can't be in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` since the column dtype is `int64`.

You can change the column dtype to be `str`, but the data won't be useful (ie you won't be able to do any date-calculations on it, though `<`, `>` should still work but lexicographically). If that's still what you wish and assuming `df` is the dataframe and the date column name is `date`:

```
def format_date_col(x):
    x = str(x)
    return '-'.join([x[:4], x[4:6], x[6:]])

    # or maybe like that for better readability:
    x = str(x)
    return '{year}-{month}-{day}'.format(year=x[:4], month=x[4:6], day=x[6:])

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(format_date_col)
```

A better approach would be to use actual date dtype:

```
from datetime import datetime 

def format_date_col(x):
    return datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d')

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(format_date_col)

print df['date'].dtype
>> datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: your def format_date_col(x) does exactly what  I need. thanks a lot!